# Modifying data in an object

Tags: php, object

I have the following function:

```
function moveUp($row_nr){
        $other_row = ($row_nr - 1);
        foreach ($this -> data as &$row){
            if ($row['row_nr'] == $other_row){
                $row['row_nr']++;
            }
            else if ($row['row_nr'] == $row_nr){
                $row['row_nr']--;
            }
        }
    }
```

`$this -> data` is an array containing arrays representing rows of fields returned by an SQL query. The purpose of this function is to move the specified row up in the order by decrementing its row_nr and incrementing the row_nr of the row that was originally above it.

Unfortunately things don't seem to be going to plan though! The row_nr doesn't seem to update in the object. Looking at other threads I've seen people suggesting to use the & operator to reference the variable specifically rather than a copy of it, but as you can see in my code I've done that and not had a whole lot of luck with it (or perhaps I'm doing it wrong!).

I've also tried the lines:

```
$row -> row_nr++;

$row -> row_nr--;
```

as I've seen in some examples posted here but no luck there either.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to why the data array in the object doesn't seem to be updating properly?

Comment: It appears that Wayne gave you an acceptable answer. You should mark it as such using the green check next to the answer so he can get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function moveUp($row_nr){
        $other_row = ($row_nr - 1);
        foreach ($this -> data as $key => $row){
            if ($row['row_nr'] == $other_row){
                $this->data[$key]['row_nr']++;
            }
            else if ($row['row_nr'] == $row_nr){
                $this->data[$key]['row_nr']--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This got the job done! Thanks! Although upon actually doing this I realised that just switching the row_nrs doesn't solve the problem and that I need to swap the two rows in the data array, but I'm sure I can handle that. <_<

Thanks dawg!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, functions get copies of arrays.

Either

a) Return the new array

or

b) `function moveUp(&$row_nr){`

To pass the array by reference.

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with the issue at hand, the issue is the object itself: `$this` isn't being passed. Looks to me like the function is a member function, so passing arguments by reference doesn't do anything, in fact invoking a method expecting a reference would issue a warning when called like so: `$instance->moveUp(2);`

Comment: But the array is being modified, which is lost upon the function completion.

Comment: Yes, but the array isn't what is being passed to the method, the array is `$this->data`, not `$rown_nr`, which is just an int: `$other_row = ($row_nr - 1);` wouldn't work with an array

Comment: It is indeed a member function.

Just to be clear the parameter $row_nr is an int that's used to find the correct row within the arrays. It's not a variable within the object.

Comment: @user1540332: Wayne gave you the answer: his take doesn't require you to mess around with references, because it accesses the data array (which, I take it, is a property) directly. If that doesn't do it for you, you'll have to provide some more info. Also add some var_dumps, echoes and stuff to see what is going on inside the function. Also: just a tip on the side: it's a good habit to specify   private/public/proteced access explicitly, not imply public access. That, and try setting your warning levels to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`